# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK in Android P Preview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement newer android sdk in my app, but it fails with :

`INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK:Failed to parse during installpacageLi at binary xml line 8 : Requires development Platform P but this is a release platform`

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "example"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 'P'
            versionCode 223
            versionName '2.2.3-BETA'
            //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
```

I have tried : Clean Project , Rebuild , Clean gradle cache and restart ...
Any idea ?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to install your app? You need to use an emulator with P preview image. pre-P devices/emulators don't work.

Comment: @laalto I'm trying to install on my physical device, where i always try the app when testing

Comment: @laalto My device is API 25 , but i am testing the app with SDK API 27currently and it is working well, but it don't work with API P preview, and don;'t know why

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From comments:

> I'm trying to install on my physical device, where i always try the app when testing. My device is API 25 , but i am testing the app with SDK API 27currently and it is working well, but it don't work with API P preview, and don;'t know why

You can only install APKs targeting preview platform versions on compatible preview platform version devices. So far only the emulator images for Android P are available.

Test your `targetSdkVersion 'P'` app on an Android P emulator. For testing on other devices, use a target SDK version of a released platform, such as 27.

Comment: Thanks for saving the day !!