# minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level when updating to Tiramisu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated to Tiramisu to be able to use the new `Manifest.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES` permission.

New gradle configuration:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion = "android-Tiramisu"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com..."
    minSdk 26
    targetSdkVersion "android-Tiramisu"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
    viewBinding true
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

But with this configuration I cannot run on my physical device (device with api 29 min api is 26).

> The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.

If will not update to Tiramisu the permission is be not found (marked in red).

Could someone explain why this happen?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing while trying to use POST_NOTIFICATION permission which is available only with the newest Android API 33...My minSdk is 21, while my device SDK is 29.. I don't get this error at all..

Comment: Apparently you can only run preview versions on preview devices i.e. use a Tiramisu emulator

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49177442/5608321